# Joining to in memory List

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have an in memory list that I am joining to results from a query using entity framework.  My list will most likely never be greater than 2500 records.  The results from the database can fluctuate, depending on the filters used and it will grow in size.  I've been able to join the results successfully but it feels a bit sluggish and I worry as the database grows that it could get worse.  Is there anything I can do to make this more efficient?  Please let me know if you need any additional information.  Thanks!

```
var query = from e in _context.Employees
            where (...filters...)
            select e;

var employees = query.AsEnumerable();
var offices = _officeService.GetAllOffices();

var employeeData = from e in employees
                   join o in offices on e.Office equals o.Code
                   select new EmployeeData
                   {
                       EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId,
                       FullName = e.FullName,
                       Office = e.Office,
                       Area = o.Area,
                       Region = o.Region,
                       OfficeName = o.Name,
                       Position = e.Position,
                       Languages = e.Languages
                   };

return employeeData;
```

Comment: Why not let the database do the JOIN?

Comment: The data in the list is pulled from a web api and does not reside in my database.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The dilemmas here:

1. `query` is an `IQueryable`. If you join it with `offices`, i.e. without `AsEnumerable()`, Entity Framework will throw an exception about primitive values, which is an obscure way of telling you that it can't translate `offices` into SQL.
2. So join in memory, i.e. with `query.AsEnumerable()`. But now all data from `query` will be pulled into memory, which has two adverse effects: neither the reduction in *numbers* of records by joining with `offices` nor the reduction in *width* of the result set by selecting only a restricted number of properties can be translated back to the SQL query.

You obviously want to benefit from both strands of data reduction.

As for the reduction in number of rows, there's no way to make Entity Framework join with local data other than lists of primitive values. Even then, joining is rather inefficient because EF has to convert the local list into a temporary SQL table (sort of), which requires a considerable amount of code. It's more efficient to use `Contains`, which translates into an `IN` statement:

```
var officesCodes = offices.Select(o => o.Code).ToList();
var employeeInfo = from e in employees
                   where officesCodes.Contains(e.Office)
                   select ...
```

Now `employeeInfo` is an `IQueryable`, so it's possible to reduce the width of the result set by projection:

```
var employeeInfo = from e in employees
                   where officesCodes.Contains(e.Office)
                   select new
                   {
                       EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId,
                       FullName = e.FullName,
                       Office = e.Office,
                       Position = e.Position,
                       Languages = e.Languages
                   };
```

This achieves the desired data reduction. But now you haven't got `EmployeeData` objects yet. Can't be done by this query, because they also contain data from `offices`. This final step can only be achieved by joining the result in memory with `offices`:

```
var employeeData = from e in employeeInfo.AsEnumerable()
                   join o in offices on e.Office equals o.Code
                   select new EmployeeData
                   {
                       EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId,
                       FullName = e.FullName,
                       Office = e.Office,
                       Area = o.Area,
                       Region = o.Region,
                       OfficeName = o.Name,
                       Position = e.Position,
                       Languages = e.Languages
                   };
```

Comment: _query is an IQueryable. If you join it with offices, Entity Framework will throw_ not quite. OP uses `AsEnumerable` so it won't throw.

Comment: @t3chb0t I mean, if you join it as such, without AsEnumerable.

Comment: It's hard to optimize this query. I was also thinking of `officesCodes.Contains` so that SQL can use `IN` but now we actually might hit the limit of it [Limit on the WHERE col IN (…) condition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069415/limit-on-the-where-col-in-condition) if there are too many offices and 2500 is not that far from it.

Comment: @t3chb0t There is a [way out](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24534217/861716), but I'd love to hear some feedback from OP on this. If a number of 2500 is hardly ever reached and it's usually far less, it may be OK.

Comment: So first of all, I tried your suggestion and it does seem to run faster so it has been optimized.  Thank you for that.  Secondly, while the total number of offices may be around 2500, I may be able to filter that list to be less since a user pulling this information will almost never need all of the results.  Should I filter my office list and update my query?

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the answer.  I went ahead and filtered my office list before joining my queries and it did optimize it further.

Answer (score 5):

Gert Arnold gave a great answer but let me suggest one more soution to try. Yes, data which is got from another source (rather than DB) can be processed in 2 ways:

1. Download as small data part from DB to local as possible and join locally (usually using `AsEnumerable()` or basically `ToList()`). You got many good thoughts on this in other answers.
2. Another one is different - upload your local data to server somehow and perform query on DB side. Uploading can be done differently: using some temp tables OR using VALUES. Fortunately there is a small extension for EF now (for both EF6 and EF Core) which you could try (It is written by me). It is [EntityFrameworkCore.MemoryJoin](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFrameworkCore.MemoryJoin) (name might be confusing, but it supports both EF6 and EF Core). As stated in author's [article](http://tsherlock.tech/2018/03/20/joining-in-memory-list-to-entity-framework-query/) (me) it modifies SQL query passed to server and injects **VALUES** construction with data from your local list. And query is executed on DB server.

So in your case you may try the following:

```
var query= from e in _context.Employees
        where (...filters...)
        select e;

// change 1: no need to use AsEnumerable now
var employees = query; 

// change 2: get IQueryable representation using EntityFrameworkCore.MemoryJoin
var offices = context.FromLocalList(_officeService.GetAllOffices());

var employeeData = from e in employees
               join o in offices on e.Office equals o.Code
               select new EmployeeData
               {
                   EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId,
                   FullName = e.FullName,
                   Office = e.Office,
                   Area = o.Area,
                   Region = o.Region,
                   OfficeName = o.Name,
                   Position = e.Position,
                   Languages = e.Languages
               };

// change 3 (suggested), let's return result list instead of IQueryable
return employeeData.ToList();
```

Using code above, query will be done on DB side. 2500 records should be ok to process (I used with 20k), but of course need to ensure this works fine for you.

Comment: _join locally_ - this isn't necessarily a good advice :-\ is there any reason you won't let the SQL Server do the job?

Comment: @t3chb0t There are different views about that going around. One says the DB should deliver as little data as possible and clean it's own data, the other says the DB should do as little as possible and if it's computationally cheaper to off-load more data, do just that. It's CPU vs bandwith basically.

Comment: It's not hard to figure out that you're the author of this library. That doesn't matter, but you should add a disclaimer, for example looking like the one [this user consistently adds to his posts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46286164/861716). For the record, out of curiosity I tried your NuGet package, but doing something similar to the example in your blog, I couldn't get it working with EF-core (2.02) and EF 6.2.0 due to various exceptions. I realize that doesn't give you much to look into, but a comment is too short to give any more detail.

Comment: OK, got it working in EF6. In EF-core it doesn't seem to recognize the EF-core `DbContext` type. Nevertheless, the first results look promising. The only thing that worries me a bit is the possible performance hit of generating value tuples when there are "many" of them. Did you do any benchmarking on that? Also, maybe you could add an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26198860/861716) and have my vote - again.

Comment: @t3chb0t Sorry, your comment confused me a lot. 1) What do you mean saying `let the SQL Server do the job`? How will SQL Server join data from DB to data from third party API? 2) Why do you think `join locally` IS my advice? I just suggested some solutions and both may work in some scenarios. (personally I prefer #2 btw) 3) Yes `local join` is not always a good idea, BUT sometimes EF basically CAN'T generate efficient query, so doing some job locally may be good. And btw EF Core does some job locally automatically.... etc

Comment: @GertArnold yes, not hard, taking in account that link is in my profile. I didn't know there is a rule on SO which states I should add such disclaimer actually, where can I read more about this? In FAQ? If possible, could you please create an issue on GitHub (https://github.com/neisbut/EntityFramework.MemoryJoin) with exception's detail? I will try to solve it. Actually I use it with EF Core and it works for me... On benchmarking - it is in my plans, but sorry currently I'm pretty loaded with current work. will try to find some time..

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I missed the point about two different data sources. You're right, there is sometimes no other way.

Comment: As for the faq: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57497/168269

Comment: @GertArnold thanks a lot, I didn't know this

Comment: Thank you @Tony for this amazing tool!

Answer (score 0):

I have recently built a simple method to do this entirely in-database, by converting the static data into a query that returns a result set of the data. This produces a standard `IQueryable` which can be fed into the rest of the query. My usecase was to perform in-database joins, but I'm sure there are many other uses.

The general strategy was to construct a query of SELECTs with provided values, that are concatenated together with UNION ALL. I avoided the `VALUES` syntax since the syntax is inexplicably different across Postgres, MySql, and MS SQL.

```sql
SELECT    "Data1A" AS columnA, "Data1B" AS columnB
UNION ALL "Data2A", "Data2B"
UNION ALL "Data3A", "Data3B"
UNION ALL "Data4A", "Data4B"
-- and so on, and so forth...
;
```

This can then be used as a subquery inside the main query, and joined on just like any other result set.

To use this with EF, the raw SQL is constructed with a `StringBuilder` and then executed using `FromSqlRaw()`.

In EF 7 and below, the only nice way to execute this SQL is to first create a `DbSet` in the `DbContext` that acts as a virtual table representing the data being returned:

```csharp
public DbSet<StaticDataEntity> StubDbSet { get; set; }

// ...

// Exclude the DbSet from all migrations, since we don't actually want it to be a real table in the database.
builder.Entity<StaticDataEntity>().HasNoKey().ToTable("tmp_stub_table", t => t.ExcludeFromMigrations());
```

EF 8 will enable returning unmapped entities from raw SQL, removing the above ceremony of creating a stub DB set entirely.

Then, you can use this extension method over that `DbSet` that generates a raw SQL query, giving you an `IQueryable` to join against.

Example entity class:

```csharp
public class StaticDataEntity {
    public string A { get;set; }
    public string B { get;set; }
}
```

```csharp
public static IQueryable<StaticDataEntity> CreateResultSetFromData(this DbSet<StaticDataEntity> dbSet, List<StaticDataEntity> values)
{
    // StaticDataEntity is the entity POCO class. This one has two properties, A and B, corresponding to two columns of data.

    var columnNames = (A: nameof(StaticDataEntity.A), B: nameof(StaticDataEntity.B));

    if (values.Count > 0)
    {
        // Create a UNION of SELECT "PredefinedDataA" AS `A`, SELECT "PredefinedDataB" AS `B`
        // This generates a temporary result set from the input values.

        string[] staticDataArray = new string[values.Count * 2];
        var queryStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < values.Count; i++)
        {
            int dataIndex = i * 2;
            if (i == 0)
            {
                queryStringBuilder.Append($"SELECT {{{dataIndex}}} AS {columnNames.A}, {{{dataIndex + 1}}} AS {columnNames.B} ");
            }
            else
            {
                queryStringBuilder.Append($"UNION SELECT {{{dataIndex}}}, {{{dataIndex + 1}}} ");
            }

            // Build one-dimensional array of the values to pass into FromSqlRaw as parameters
            staticDataArray[dataIndex] = values[i].A;
            staticDataArray[dataIndex + 1] = values[i].B;
        }

        return dbSet.FromSqlRaw(queryStringBuilder.ToString(), staticData).AsNoTracking();
    }
    else
    {
        // No data, return empty result set
        return dbSet.FromSqlRaw(
            $"SELECT NULL AS {columnNames.A}, NULL AS {columnNames.B} WHERE FALSE",
            null
            ).AsNoTracking();
    }
}
```

Now, you can do:

```csharp
// TODO: Populate data list with entries
var data = new List<StaticDataEntity>();

// Create static data query
IQueryable<StaticDataEntity> dataQuery = dbContext.StubDbSet.CreateResultSetFromData(data);

// Join static data column A to in-database "SomeEntities" table column C.
// Return static A and B, and database column C and D.
var resultQuery = dbContext.SomeEntities.Join(
    dataQuery,
    se => se.C,
    sde => sde.A,
    (se, sde) => new {
        sde.A, sde.B, se.C, se.D
    });

// Execute the query
var result = await resultQuery.ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! This is all good work, but it's lacking a _review_ of the code in the question.  Can you update your description to explain what's better about your approach, and what trade-offs are being made?